# Word "Array" is Appearing on Blog Posts Page

Tags: php, templates

I'm getting the word "Array" coming up on my blog POSTS page when I use the below code. I have a feeling that it relates to this line:

I am using a similar template for my PORTFOLIO and NEWS pages where the wording is slightly different on this line ("showportcat" and "shownewscat" instead of "get_the_category") and it should be displaying the categories but instead, the word 'array' is in it's place.

I've tried "showpostcat" but that didnt' work so I wonder if I need to be re-wording it? Or maybe the problem is on another part of the code which I've included below?

```
        <div class="greyblock">
            <h4 class="nomar"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h4>
            <div class="sep"></div>

                <?php echo get_the_category(get_the_ID()); ?>

                <div class="clear"></div>
                <ul class="blogpost_list columns2">

                <?php
                $temp = $wp_query;
                $wp_query = null;
                $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'posts_per_page' => get_option("posts_per_page"),   
                );


                if (isset($_GET['slug'])) {
                $args['tax_query']=array( 
                        array( 
                            'taxonomy' => 'postcat',  
                            'field' => 'slug',  
                            'terms' => $_GET['slug']  
                         )
                    );
                }



                $wp_query->query($args);
                ?>
                <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
                #We have:
                #get_permalink() - Full url to post;
                #get_the_title() - Post title;
                #get_the_content() - Post text;
                #get_post_time('U', true) - unix timestamp

                $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );   


                echo "
                <li class='pc'>
                        <img alt='".get_the_title()."' src='".TIMTHUMBURL."?w=400&h=400&src=".$featured_image[0]."'>
                        <h4>".get_the_title()."</h4>";
                        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'postcat');
                        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {

                        $draught_links = array();

                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                            $draught_links[] = $term->name;
                        }

                        $on_draught = join( ", ", $draught_links );
                        }

                echo "
                <p>".get_the_excerpt()."</p>
                    <a href='".get_permalink()."' class='read'>Read more</a>                        
                    <br class='clear' />
                </li>
                ";  

                 endwhile; ?>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php get_pagination() ?>
        <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$categories = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is still there. I'm guessing it relates to the way I am wording one of the below two lines as it is 'showportcat' for portfolios and 'shownewscat' for news but 'showpostcat' doesn't work for posts so I just can't figure it out:

```
 <?php echo get_the_category(get_the_ID()); ?>
 **OR**
 'taxonomy' => 'postcat',
```

Comment: `var_dump` the variable so you can see what you're actually working with.